# c++ converting binary string to integer or comparing 2 strings to find number of differences

Tags: c++, string, binary, bitset

I used bitset to convert 2 numbers to a string representation of binary numbers. I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine number of differences now based on this (I needed the integer converted to binary for other reasons within the code). Anyways, here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
1110 and 1100 should return 1, 1111 and 0000 should return 4, 1110 and 1110 should return 0;
```

I have the first number stored in a 2d vector of pairs, like grid[i][j].second. The 2nd number is an argument passed in, so it's called binaryObserv. I found there's a to_ulong function built in to bitset, but that's that working on my string that I used bitset to convert earlier in my program. I could keep the 2nd one as an integer and figured if I did an exclusive or with the 2 numbers, then convert to binary, I could iterate through the result to count the number of 1's set. However, I can't get the first one (the string) converted back to an integer. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha, nvm figured it out. I went with my first attempted approach with comparing the strings (not putting back to int). Here it is for anyone interested:

```
for(uint i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++){
      for(uint j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++){
        int acc = 0;
          cout << "num in grid: " <<  grid[i][j].second<< endl;
        for(uint k = 0; k < (grid[i][j].second).length(); k++){
          if((grid[i][j].second).at(k) != binaryObserv.at(k)){
            acc++;
          } 
        }
        cout << "num of differences: " << acc << endl;
      }
    }
```